# Force CCProxy to use a specific NIC

Tags: networking, proxy, proxy-server

I checked all other posts regarding this matter. I tried with ForceBindIP, but it simply doesn't work (it continues to send the packets through the wrong NIC).

I looked at every setting in CCProxy has and couldn't find anything to make it use a specific network adapter.

Anyone has an idea how to force it to use a specific NIC in a computer with 2 NICs (both connected to the internet)?

Comment: Isn't the software simply binding the specified ip and then sending out the packets according to the route table? If so you're trying to create a policy based route situation where you set the next hop for the packets to be the gateway of choice. How this is done depends on the used operating system.

Comment: @Paul that's what I thought, but even if when set the "Server Bind IP Address" to the 2nd NIC IP address, it still seems to send the data through the first NIC...

Comment: binding an ip will only partially influence the routing choice made for outbound traffic. This is why it is still sending the data out on the first NIC with the IP address of the second NIC. If you want to influence this behavior for only CCProxy you need to look into policy based routing. In FreeBSD my suggestions would be ipfw with the fwd rule or using a secondary routing table for this. You didn't specify an os so this is just an example at this time...

Comment: @Paul the OS is Windows 7, but I seem to have found a working solution, though I'm not really sure why it's working... if you understand it I would love to hear an explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, in addition to binding to the relevant NIC's IP address, I needed to check the "Enable Multiple IPs Outgoing" checkbox.

I'm not sure exactly why, but it fixed the problem...

[image: CCProxy advanced options networks tab]

Comment: To me it seems this option is telling the software to overrule the routing table based on the selected bind IP and probably the same subnet gateway. In essence what I meant with a policy route.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer